# Take next photo with live preview

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm customizing a camera app like what is provided in [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera).

I use surfaceview and surfaceholder.callback to make a live preview. The live preview works right with first photo and later it stops. It just displays photo that I took. Mean the live preview don't work. And second photo my camera dont work. So reboot my phone for using camera.

So how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [the reference docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html), taking a photo using `takePicture()` will stop the preview. You need to call `startPreview()` to get it going again.

Here's the relevant section:

> After taking a picture, preview display will have stopped. To take more photos, call `startPreview()` again first.